# Xamarin.Forms Change placeholder color and textcolor of entry ONLY on ONE platform (iOS)

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app i am using this entry:

```
                        <Entry
                             x:Name="entry_passwort_login"
                             PlaceholderColor="#ffffff"
                             TextColor="#ffffff"
                             IsPassword="true"
                             FontFamily="Galvji-01.ttf"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="Start"
                             Placeholder="Passwort"/>
```

It looks great on Android, since the background is black. I also made changes in the styles.xml to get the highlighted color of the element to yellow.

But iOS renders an entry with a white box in the background:

[image]

As you can see, therefore neither the placeholder NOR the actual text that is written on them is visible. But I dont want to change the whole background.

How can I make the placeholder and text color of the entries for IOS ONLY black, while leaving all the android set up untouched?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to do it from XAML? Or with a style? Or you don't care? You're looking for this either way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sepecific other color in the iOS. For example, I set it `PlaceholderColor` to Red in iOS like following code.

```
            <Entry
                             x:Name="entry_passwort_login"
                             TextColor="#ffffff"
                             FontFamily="Galvji-01.ttf"
                             IsPassword="true"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="Start"
                             Placeholder="Passwort">
                <Entry.PlaceholderColor>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="Red"></On>
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="#ffffff"></On>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Entry.PlaceholderColor>
                
            </Entry>
```

Comment: if above answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue